# (ORIG_EAX*4) in ptrace calls

Tags: c, linux, ptrace, systems-programming

I was going through an article [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100) and was trying out the code snippet I have copied out below :-

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/user.h>   /* For constants
                                   ORIG_EAX etc */
int main()
{   pid_t child;
    long orig_eax;
    child = fork();
    if(child == 0) {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);
        orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                          child, 4 * ORIG_EAX,
                          NULL);
        printf("The child made a "
               "system call %ld\n", orig_eax);
        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have a doubt regarding what `ORIG_EAX` is exactly and why `4*ORIG_EAX` is passed onto the ptrace call. I initially assumed that `ORIG_EAX`, `EBX`, `ECX` etc would be the offsets into a particular structure where the values of the registers would be stored.

So I decided to print the value of ORIG_EAX just after the wait by using `printf("origeax = %ld\n", ORIG_EAX);`. The value was `11`. So, my earlier assumption regarding the offsets was wrong.

I understand that the `wait` call is terminated when the child has a state change(in this case, issues a system call) and that ORIG_EAX would contain the system call number.

However, why is ORIG_EAX * 4 passed onto the ptrace call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The parameter is an offset into the [user_regs_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/user_32.h#L77). Note that each of these is an `unsigned long`, so to get the 11th entry (`orig_eax`) the offset in bytes is 44, (provided you're on an x86 machine of course).

Comment: What about dfferences between 32 and 64-bit? Shouldn't we compile-time-case on that?

Comment: Further..., is this ptrace x86 only? If not we need some more general target-independent way of doing this!

Comment: There's definitely a definition for an AMD64 `user_regs_struct`, but I'm not sure if you can mix and match architectures. IIRC the comments in the `ptrace` mentioned the separate headers were a problem. Since `ptrace` is a syscall it should work (you just might have to switch the offsets for each architecture manually) but I can't say I've ever tried it.

Comment: That seems to unnecessarily expose an implementation detail; why doesn't ptrace do *4 itself?

Comment: on Ubuntu 18.0.4, the path to "sys/user.h" is "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/user.h"